# Javascript: Attaching events from a string, variables evaluation in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, variable-declaration

I am positive I asked this question in the wrong way. I am attempting to pass a string such as `onClick="someFunc(arg1,arg2...)"` to a javascript parser.

The parser should create an onClick event for someFunc with args (arg1, arg2 etc) .

My issue is that as the text is passed through the parser, the scope of the variable that holds the string name of someFunc is being passed down so that the attached events all register as the last declared string.

In the code below, attributes._onClick could be the string 'onClick="someFunc(arg1,arg2);" for one element followed by 'onClick="otherFunc(argA,argB);" for another element as the parser moves through the string.

The output in the browser (Firefox V14.01) has the event function always registering as otherFunc. So f_name in the closure is not evaluating as the variable but instead just registers as the last value of f_name declared throughout parsing the entire block.

I am not familiar with scope to the degree that I need to be to figure this out. Does anybody know a way I can attach the events in this manner (im trying to avoid going outside the parser to add the events) ?

```
           temp = attributes._onClick ;
            var x = 0 ;
            var f_name,f_args ;
            while(temp[x] != '') {
                temp[x] = temp[x].replace(')','').split('(') ;//remove paranthesis and separate func name from args
                f_name = temp[x][0] ;
                f_args = temp[x][1].split(',') ;//turn string of args into array
                el.onclick = function() { window[f_name].apply(el,f_args) ; }
                x++ ;
            }
```

Comment: You know that an "onclick" value need not be a function call right? It can be any JavaScript statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're tripping over a pitfall in JavaScript that causes the same problem in various different ways to almost everybody at some point.

The variable "f_name" is **shared** among all the functions you're creating. That is, though each iteration of the loop creates a new function, there's only one "f_name".  Thus, all functions see the same value in it, that being the value it had on the last iteration.

There are several related solutions. One way is to wrap the statement that establishes the event handler in another anonymous function, one that you immediately invoke. That'll allow you to create a **copy** of "f_name", for exclusive use by one handler.

```
               el.onclick = function(name) {
                return function() { window[name].apply(el,f_args) ; };
               }(f_name);
```

Interestingly, there are probably hundreds of variations on this question here on SO.

Comment: I tried the code you have here and my guess is I havent quite wrapped my head around what you are doing but it isnt working for me. f_name is still using only the last value it was assigned. Correct me if Im wrong but using the closure should 'set' the variable and return it to the outer function?

Comment: Figured it out. I am not familiar with the syntax still but I used your answer. Thanks Pointy.

Comment: @MagicLasso ok glad to have helped - the key is that in the function, I used "name" instead of "f_name" - I did it to make it clear that I was using the copy, but maybe that was confusing. Anyway I'm glad it's working!